# markdown spanning comma seems ineffective

Tags: support, bug, markdown

When I tried to bold-face words spanning comma for English grammar questions that whether or not comma should be used, e.g. "unified**, will** induce the risks of strangling the usage of ...", that comma and following words put inside pair of double asterisks won't bold-faced in preview.
I may not understand the correct way to do that or it's just how things are designed this way? I ended up moving the opening double asterisks in front of the word before the comma I wanted to highlight.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to clarify what you mean please?

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. Absent a spec for SE flavor of Markdown, I refer to [CommonMark spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.28/#emphasis-and-strong-emphasis):

> A left-flanking delimiter run is a delimiter run that is (a) not followed by Unicode whitespace, and (b) not followed by a punctuation character, or preceded by Unicode whitespace or a punctuation character.

and

> A double ** can open strong emphasis iff it is part of a left-flanking delimiter run.

So, one cannot bold a part of text beginning with a comma using Markdown. One can use HTML though:

> unified**, will** induce

produced with `unified<b>, will</b> induce`

Comment: Why does this limitation exist?